# Disable null on form:input field

Tags: html, forms, spring-mvc

I am using a `<form:input>` on my jsp. The input field should be editable but not nullable. Is there a way to handle this on the client side? i,e, disable the deletion of the value in the field but keep the field editable.

Comment: Does the field have a default value or are you just asking to make it a 'required' field?

Comment: Thanks. yes the field has a default value on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling deletion would be inconvenient for users. It would be better to check the value when focus leaves the field and show error message if it's empty. For example, using jQuery:

```
<form:input id = "f" ... />
```

.

```
var f = $("#f");
f.blur(function() {
    if (!f.val()) {
        ... // show error message
    }
});
f.change(function() {
    if (f.val()) {
        ... // hide error message
    }
});
```